# Is there a way to pin an exe in taskbar using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm extracting an zip folder contains an EXE file using python. Once extracted, I want to pin the EXE file to the task bar. Is there a way to do that using python?

Comment: Windows? Linux (and which desktop environment if so)? Something else? In general, pinning should be up to the user; don't force your junk on them; if they use it enough and desire pinning, they can pin it themselves.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm using Windows 7 and the EXE won't pin themselves as it is not an installation. It is a extract-and-use type of application.

Answer (score 0):

[Programs aren't supposed to do this in the first place; there is no supported way to do it even with an installer, so Python isn't going to be any more supported. If you forcibly pin your program, *your program is a bad actor*.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141230-00/?p=43273/)